# Why isn't this code printing my array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, loops

I have an integer array sorting program here but I have a problem: whenever I run the program I sometimes get a "The stack around the variable 'numbers' was corrupted" message and sometimes it just repeatedly prints out the number 8. Here's my code (compiled in Visual C++ 2010):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int tmp=0;
    tmp = *x;
    *x  = *y;
    *y  = tmp;
    tmp = 0;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[13] = {8,16,23,487,2,301,48,0,13,10,644,12};

    int size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int);

    //sort

    int i = 0;
    int* a = &numbers[0];
    int* b = &numbers[1];


    while(i < size){

        if(*a > *b){
            swap(a, b);
        }

        *a++;
        *b++;
         i++;
    }

    //Print our results
    int loopIterator = 0;
    int numToPrint = 0;
    while(loopIterator < size){
        cout << numbers[numToPrint] << endl;
        loopIterator++;
    }


    system("PAUSE");

}
```

Comment: and the lord said: shall integers always be 4... *sigh*, use sizeof(int).

Comment: `int size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int);`

Comment: Both the above solutions are suboptimal.  Better: `size_t size = sizeof numbers / sizeof numbers[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you never increment `numToPrint`, therefore you are never going to print more than the value of `numbers[0]`.  At the very least change your code to:

```
while(loopIterator < size){
    cout << numbers[numToPrint++] << endl;
    loopIterator++;
}
```

Secondly, since your `while` loop uses the test `i < size`, you are, on the last iteration of the loop, going to be accessing memory outside of `numbers` for your `b` pointer, and possibly swapping that value into the last slot of `numbers` (i.e., where `a` is pointing to).  You want to change your test to `i < (size - 1)` to avoid that scenario.  For instance, if at `i == 0` you have `a = &numbers[0]` and `b = &numbers[1]`, then by the time that `i == 12`, you are going to end up with `a = &numbers[12]` and `b = &numbers[13]` ... the value that `b` is pointing to in this instance is past the end of the array.  Depending on how your compiler has setup the stack, and the way you've allocated `numbers` on the stack, this could actually play some havoc with your program should you end up  with `b` pointing into the activation record data-structures for your `main()` function, and in-turn corrupting it.

Comment: why have two indexes? If he wants a counting loop he should use a counting loop. i.e. `for(int i(0); i < size; ++i) cout << numbers[i] << endl;`

Comment: That works as well ... I was just pointing out an error in his code and a quick way to fix it that only adds two more characters.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are implementing the array sort as an exercise.  This doesn't really answer your question but I thought I'd post for reference, regardless.  Here's one way to achieve the desired result using the STL:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
  int numbers[] = { 8, 16, 23, 487, 2, 301, 48, 0, 13, 10, 644, 12 };
  size_t const size = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);

  int * const begin = numbers;
  int * const end   = numbers + size;

  std::sort(begin, end);
  std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Yay for STL. On a side note he could also use `std::set` container and get this entire program down to 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing that immediately jumps out at me is that you are never incrementing numToPrint so it will print out numbers[0], size number of times.

I would rewrite your printing section to

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << numbers[i] << endl;
```

With that you can get rid of the print results section of your code, as the above is a cleaner way of doing the same thing.

The error message you are getting is probably because you are writing to parts of memory that you shouldn't be touching. This is probably a result of using "sizeof" incorrectly. It returns the number of elements in numbers, not the memory size. Would recommend checking the comments on the actual question for the correct solution to your second issue.

Comment: Note that this is one of the two errors that the OP reported ;)

Comment: Heh, yea, was just addressing the one thing I saw for sure, went ahead and edited to answer both, with the solution to the incorrect use of sizeof going to yi_H.

Answer (score 0):

This sort won't work as you only run through your list of numbers once, so it will swap adjacent items but it won't sort the list (it's kind of half an implementation of a bubble sort)

Comment: `sizeof numbers` is the size measured in bytes, not elements.  Dividing by the size of an element is correct (and it should be calculated, e.g. `sizeof numbers[0]`)

Comment: Well I was too slow to take off the downvote before it locked in.  Your answer still doesn't actually answer the question though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have an operator precedence problem here:

```
*b++;
```

In fact, the compiler should have warned you about an operator with no side-effects (the `*`).

Besides that, pointer `b` will go off the end of the array, since it starts at element 1 and is advanced `size` times, it will end up pointing to `numbers[size+1]`.  If the compiler optimizes away the useless dereference, that won't be a problem, but on the previous pass you call `swap(numbers+size-1, numbers+size)` and that writes off the end of the array, causing the stack corruption you detected.